# Making a chart bigger in size

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to get a bigger chart. However, the figure method from matplotlib does not seem to be working properly.

I get a message, which is not an error:

```
<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0xa25f7f0>
```

My code:

```py
import pandas.io.data as web
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline
...
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
df2['media']= df2['SPY']*.6 + df2['TLT']*.4
df2.plot()
plt.show()
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You can skip the first `plt.figure()` and just use the argument figsize:

```
df2.plot(figsize=(20,10))
```

See [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html).

Comment: The link to documentation references nothing valuable. Could somebody please update it?

Comment: Pointing the link back to version 0.23.1 because the documentation for the current 0.25.1 omits all method detail.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to pass the current axes to `DataFrame.plot()`:

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
df2.plot(ax=plt.gca());
```

or create a figure and axes and pass the relevant axes explicitly:

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
df2.plot(ax=axs);
```

or plot each column one-by-one in a `plt.plot()` call:

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.plot(df2.index, df2['SPY'], df2.index, df2['TLT']);
```